# ngx-socket-io - Can not receive and send events

Tags: node.js, angular, websocket

I have implemented `socket-io` server in my app and I am using `ngx-socket-io` for my `Angular` application communicating with that server.

My server implementation:

```js
const io = socketio(server);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('connection!')
    socket.emit('notification');
});
```

After connecting to my app, the `connection!` message is printed successfully, means the client successfully linked to the WS server.

But my `notification` event listener is not receiving any events...

My `WebSocketService`:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';

@Injectable()
export class WebSocketService {
    constructor(
        private socket: Socket,
    ) {}

    public getEventListener() {
        return this.socket.fromEvent('notification');
    }
}
```

Subscription (In other service):

```js
@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
    ...

    constructor(
        private wsService: WebSocketService,
    ) {
        console.log('Test')
        this.wsService.getEventListener().subscribe(() => console.log(123));
    }

    ...
}
```

`Test` is printed but 123 is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My server configuration was invalid. I put my server URL with `/api` route instead of the main route.

App Module Imports:

```js
SocketIoModule.forRoot({ url: 'http://localhost:3000/api' }),
```

Fixed:

```js
SocketIoModule.forRoot({ url: 'http://localhost:3000' }),
```